# Dapper and CsvHelper ignore columns dynamically

Tags: c#, dapper, csvhelper

I'm using Dapper to query an SQL procedure to which I don't know the returned columns.
I want to write the results to a CSV file with CsvHelper.
In runtime, I want to dynamically ignore some of the columns.
CsvHelper has a mapping configuration which accepts only predefined classes.

```
var records = sqlCon.Query(sqlProcedure); //dynamic columns

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var map = new CsvHelper.Configuration.DefaultClassMap<dynamic>();
...
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Comment: CsvHelper can write dynamic objects out of the box: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-dynamic-objects/. There shouldn't be a need for a class map.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to do it with mapping. It is possible to manually write them out and ignore certain columns.

```cs
void Main()
{
    dynamic obj1 = new ExpandoObject();
    obj1.Id = 1;
    obj1.Name = "Bill";
    obj1.IgnoreProperty = "Please ignore me";

    dynamic obj2 = new ExpandoObject();
    obj2.Id = 2;
    obj2.Name = "Brenda";
    obj2.IgnoreProperty = "Please also ignore me";
    
    var records = new List<dynamic>
    {
        obj1,
        obj2
    };

    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {       
        var recordDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)records.First();
        
        var properties = recordDictionary.Keys;
        
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property != "IgnoreProperty")
            {
                csv.WriteField(property);
            }               
        }
        
        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            var expanded = (IDictionary<string, object>)record;
            
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property != "IgnoreProperty")
                {
                    csv.WriteField(expanded[property]);
                }
            }
            
            csv.NextRecord();
        }       
    }
}
```